# Get statistical distribution of multivalue entry in Splunk

Tags: splunk

I am starting with this query to show which types of products our top customers buy

````
``` get all purchases ```
index=customer_data action=purchase 
``` narrow down to purchases from our top 100 customers (based on purchase count) ```
[search index=customer_data action=purchase top limit=100 user_id | table user_id] 
``` show type of products that each user purchased ```
| stats count by user_id, list(product_category)
````

This will give some output like this:

```
user_id | values(product_category)
------------------------------------
1234    | clothing, clothing, clothing, food
2345    | electronics, electronics, food, food
```

I need one additional piece of information: the ratio of the product categories, for each user. I need this output instead. The format of the distributions is not important

```
user_id | values(product_category)
------------------------------------
1234    | clothing=75%, food=25%
2345    | electronics=50%, food=50%
```

I would think it would be something like this:

````
``` get all purchases ```
index=customer_data action=purchase 
``` narrow down to purchases from our top 100 customers (based on purchase count) ```
[search index=customer_data action=purchase top limit=100 user_id | table user_id] 
``` show type of products that each user purchased ```
| stats count by user_id, statistical_distribution(product_category)
````

but I can't find any such function ...

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to break the multivalue field into separate entries

This is one way to do it:

```
| makemv delim="," product_category
| mvexpand product_category
| stats values(product_category) as vpc dc(product_category) as dpc count by user_id
```